# Use contain in Custom Query Pagination - CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am using `contain` behavior in cakePHP in `controllers` but I need to use the same in `Model`. In default `ORM` methods, I can use `contain` with normal query but I need this to be done with `paging`. I saw this article of [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) but it is not working with `contain`. Here is my code which I am trying

```
public function paginate($model = null, $conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {

        $limit = 1;
        $group = 'Test.id';
        $modelObj = $model;
        if (is_null($model)) {
            $modelObj = $this;
        }
        return $modelObj->find(
                        'all', compact('conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'page', 'recursive', 'group', 'extra')
        );
}
```

The callee of this function is

```
$contain["contain"] = array(
            "User" => array(
                "fields" => array(
                    "User.first_name"
                )
            )
        );
$tests = $this->paginate(null, $conditionsTest, array('Test.*'), "Test.paper_name ASC", $requestData["limit"] / 2, $requestData["page"], 1, $contain);
```

I am passing `contain` but it's not working. Any single opinion will help a lot to me.

Comment: Have you added `containable` behavior on your model? like `public $actsAs = array('Containable');`

Comment: What is `$model->find` returning? Is it returning any data, just not with the containable?

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan yes I did

Comment: @romellem it is returning based on `recursive`